# Adjusting number format using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have this statement nested in an IF-Statement under a scenario. I would like it to format column 2 into a Accounting number without decimal places. How can this be done using VB.net? The current code gives me ex: `1,000,000.00` on an input of `1000000`. I noticed excel has buttons for adding or subtracting decimal places. Could these be called within VB.net? Thanks!

```
    Lo.ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow).NumberFormat = "ACCOUNTING"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Lo.ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow).NumberFormat = "#0,000.00"
```

You may find help in this [Article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-numberformats-in-excel12233)

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you want, you can do:

```
math.floor(*insert the value or variable you want here*)
```

What that does is it changes the number in the parameter to the biggest integer lower than the parameter.

Hope this works :)